# OpenCV freezes while trying to run VideoCapture(0)

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I am playing around with OpenCV. I am following the documentation example ([link](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html))

I installed GTK webcam application on Ubuntu to validate that my webcam works. I am able to start the webcam and see the video feedback in GTK.

I added some print message in the tutorial code to see where I get.
I added a print before and after this line: `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

All I get, when running the Python file, is the print that I added before the `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` and nothing else.

I tried increasing the `waitKey` to 20, 40, 100 but it didn't help.

Does anyone know why it does not get further and display the frame?

My code:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2 

videoFeed = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
while (True): 
    ret, frame = videoFeed.read() 
    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    cv2.imshow('Feed', frame_gray) 
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF = ord("q"): 
        break 
videoFeed.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My setup:

- Windows 10 host
- Ubuntu 18.04 guest host
- Integrated Webcam
- Using PIP to install python module (numpy, scipi, pillow, open_cv, etc.)
- Using venv python

Comment: Hi Georgy, 
I was playing around trying to understand why it freezes and I found something.
I do not understand, but I did got the frame window opened.

Here's what I did  :

Started my webcam (GTK) and ran my python file.
As expected, it froze at `VideoCapture(0)`

I closed the webcam and the frame, with a picture (I guess the last one before it closed) was displayed.

I was under the impression that the webcam feed would be appearing in the frame continuously until the "q" key was pressed ... not a picture before the webcam is closed ?

What am I misunderstanding ?

Comment: Hi Shawn, it's the code provided in the OP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in your code at `if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF = ord("q"):`. You should've gotten a syntax error here though.

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2 

videoFeed = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
while (True): 
    ret, frame = videoFeed.read()
    if ret == False:
        print("Failed to retrieve frame")
        break 
    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    cv2.imshow('Feed', frame_gray) 
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord("q"): 
        break 
videoFeed.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Tested your code. Works fine. Only other suggestion is to check whether your Ubuntu guest has permission to access your webcam. If you're using VirtualBox I remember seeing an option for this in the interface